# node is not recognized, even after adding it to System Variables

Tags: node.js, npm, path, windows-7

I have installed node 8.9.4 recently. When tried hitting node commands, it is not recognized. Then Added the PATH in 'System Variables' & 'Account environment variables', still no hope.
Works when, `SET PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs\8.9.4` on every instance.

Comment: adding a folder to system wide PATH requires reboot.

Comment: Hi magicandre1981, Thank You :). I did reboot too, Found the problem. It got installed inside folder 8.9.4 - "C:\Program Files\nodejs\8.9.4". Just copied the files and pasted inside "C:\Program Files\nodejs", It worked.